# How to populate UsbRegDeviceList in a .NET app running LibUsbDotNet "Getting Started Example"

Tags: c#, vb.net, usb, libusb, libusbdotnet

When I run it, the allDevices list is empty.

I started a new VB.NET console project, and installed Nuget LibUsbDotNet.

My code is this:

```
Imports System
Imports LibUsbDotNet
Imports LibUsbDotNet.Info
Imports LibUsbDotNet.Main
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel



Module Module1

        Public  MyUsbDevice As UsbDevice

        Public  Sub Main(args As String())
            ' Dump all devices and descriptor information to console output.
            Dim allDevices As UsbRegDeviceList = UsbDevice.AllDevices
            For Each usbRegistry As UsbRegistry In allDevices
                If usbRegistry.Open(MyUsbDevice) Then
                    Console.WriteLine(MyUsbDevice.Info.ToString())
                    For iConfig As Integer = 0 To MyUsbDevice.Configs.Count - 1
                        Dim configInfo As UsbConfigInfo = MyUsbDevice.Configs(iConfig)
                        Console.WriteLine(configInfo.ToString())

                        Dim interfaceList As ReadOnlyCollection(Of UsbInterfaceInfo) = configInfo.InterfaceInfoList
                        For iInterface As Integer = 0 To interfaceList.Count - 1
                            Dim interfaceInfo As UsbInterfaceInfo = interfaceList(iInterface)
                            Console.WriteLine(interfaceInfo.ToString())

                            Dim endpointList As ReadOnlyCollection(Of UsbEndpointInfo) = interfaceInfo.EndpointInfoList
                            For iEndpoint As Integer = 0 To endpointList.Count - 1
                                Console.WriteLine(endpointList(iEndpoint).ToString())
                            Next
                        Next
                    Next
                End If
            Next


            ' Free usb resources.
            ' This is necessary for libusb-1.0 and Linux compatibility.
            UsbDevice.[Exit]()

            ' Wait for user input..
            Console.ReadKey()
        End Sub

End Module
```

MY DESKTOP USB DEVICES...

[image]

Comment: So what does the Control Panel > Device Mgr say ? You have a few USB devices plugged in?

Comment: Any difference if you run Visual Studio as Admin?

Comment: Yes.  Added list above...   I will try VS as admin

Comment: VS as Admin had no effect...still no list of devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe my desktop that I was doing this on is too old, though I recently upgraded to Win 10.  So solve problem, I used new Win 10 laptop, installed and ran filter (sub-)driver and selected my laptop's webcam (as a test VID&PID), installed libUsb-Win32, created a .NET console project (I did both VB and C#), did VS > proj > Refs > NUGET > browsed LibUsbDotNet, installed it, pasted the 1st example from Sourceforge's libUsbDotNet, and it worked great:  It connected to the webcam driver (selected by the filter sub-driver), and read the correct VID&PID.  (example reported error because webcam driver did not respond to polling, but this is expected).

Comment: The driver developer would have coded return error codes. Keep that old machine, just encase the day comes where a customer gets the same. Like you say though this would be easier to cover in the "Minimum PC Requirements".